# Failure accessing a variable through its adress from another application

Tags: pointers, dynamic, heap-memory, memory-address

I am working on a Qt application on my raspberry pi 4 and I want to create a dynamic variable and to use it in my Qt application , it is a counter and I don't want it to be reinitialized at zero on every execution of the application, I want to just use the address and increment the value on each execution.

so in my raspberry pi I created a variable

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main (void)
{
        int *p;
        p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); 
        *p=10;

        printf("%p",p);
        //free(p);
return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and this is the output, so the adress of the variable created is 0xfa9150

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -Wall  impulsions.c -o impulsions
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./impulsions 
0xfa9150
```

in my Qt application I tried to read the value of the address but couldn't

```
int* counter=new int;
    counter=0xfa9150;

    qDebug()<<"counter"<< *counter;
    delete counter;
```

and I had this error

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
     counter=0xfa9150;
              ^~~~~~~~
```

can someone please explain to me how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory spaces of different processes on your system (e.g. the Qt application and your program with the counter) are mostly disjoint. Even when they use the same addresses - those are *virtual*, not physical, memory addresses, and get translated upon use, (typically) into addresses in physical memory.

That means that the Qt application does not, and cannot, have access to a counter variable in another process' memory space.

So... you will need another approach. Some possibilities:

- The Qt application communicates with your monitor mini-app over some some socket.
- No second process, but the Qt application locks a file, opens that file, reads the current counter from it, adds 1, writes it back, closes and unlocks.
- Use some existing utility/system facility which keeps track of execution statistics (I don't know of one personally, but it might exist, depending on which OS you're running).

Comment: thank you for clarifying, I will try to make it work with one of the possibilities that you proposed

Comment: @mina: If this answers your question, then please accept the answer; and if you like it, then please upvote it. That's all the thanks we need :-)

Comment: I already upvoted you answer but I wanted also to thank you :-)